# how to get the key value 1 in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i am using jquery for loop ,  i want to display the results in table .from there display like 1 2 3 ... so i am using key, but here key is start with **zero**  but i need like 1(one), how can do this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Create key value pair array, or increment index value

Comment: just add `1` to your `index` as you display it

Comment: How can do please update your answer

Comment: index is 0 base... so need to increment it

Comment: using *jquery* is redundant for such simple case. Learn `Array.prototype.forEach()`

Answer (score 0):

`alert( (index+1) + ": " + value );`
should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why you want this. 
You can increment in index value like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index+1 + ": " + value );
});
</script>
```